# How to use environment specific test data in Karate

Tags: automation, cucumber, karate

I would like to know how it is possible to use different data sets on runtime when executing tests in various environments. I have read the documentation but i am unable to find the best solution for this scenario.

Requirement: Execute a test in QA environment and then execute the same test in SIT. However, use different data in the request e.g customerIds. The reason for this is because the data setup in each environment is very different.

Would appreciate it if you could propose the best solution for this scenario.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here in the documentation, you can find an explanation on how to do this : https://github.com/intuit/karate#environment-specific-config

Then you can simply specify the environment when launching karate :

```
mvn test -DargLine="-Dkarate.env=e2e"
```

And all your tests will be able to use the variables you've defined for the specified environment.

Edit: another hint, in your config file, specify the path of a file. Now, depending on your env, you'll be able to read a different file, containing all your data.

Edit after your comment :
Let's say you defined two environments, "qa" and "prod".
For every data where there is a difference between the two, simply create two files : `myFile-qa.json` and `myFile-prod.json`.

Now, in your tests, when you want to read a file, just read `('myFile-'+env+'.json')`. And just like that, you read the correct file depending on your defined environment.

Comment: Thank you for your contribution. My question was more around using specific data for an environment rather than environment switching. In terms of the latter part of your response, it suggests that all of my data will need to be read from one file. Would it be possible to have the various data files stored in multiple locations and then use them in requests?

Comment: Yes of course. I just gave a simple example, I'll edit my answer.

Comment: @Adrien - Legend! That sounds ideal and a potential fix to my problem. Will give it a go, thank you :)